# PHP file upload fails when file size above a certain size only

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP file upload snippet (both HTML and PHP code), upload works fine with smaller file sizes, several KB, 20KB, however, starting from 30KB or above, upload will fail, $_FILES['userfile']['error'] displays an error code of 2: meaning "UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE" which refers to MAX_FILE_SIZE setting on form, currently it's 200000 (200KB, big enough); I checked all relevant PHP settings, not seems problem.

Listed below are all source code, PHP settings, and PC environment, can anyone kindly advise for solutions? Thanks in advance.

### HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"/> 
<title>fupload</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File upload test</h3> 
<form method="POST" action="fupload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" />    
    <input name="userfile" type="file" size="70"/>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### PHP code  (fupload.php)

```
<?php

// For test/debug
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);


$uploaddir = './up/file/';
$uploadfile = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '$uploadfile='.$uploadfile;
echo '<br />Full upload filespec='.$uploaddir.$uploadfile;

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$uploadfile)) {
    echo "File upload done successfully!\n";

// For test/debug, display error code
echo '$_FILES[userfile][error]: '.$_FILES['userfile']['error'];

} else {
    echo "File upload failed!\n";

// For test/debug, display error code
echo '$_FILES[userfile][error]: '.$_FILES['userfile']['error'];
}
echo '<pre>';
?>
```

### Related PHP settings

```
php.ini:
  upload_tmp_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
  upload_max_filesize=20M
  post_max_size=100M
  memory_limit=128M

(Apache) httpd.conf:  
  LimitRequestBody 202400

  Apache default doc root changed to a folder on D:
```

### Used PC environment

```
Latest XAMPP, Windows 7
C: available size: 14.5GB
D: available size: 36.2GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Through lot more tries, instead of a nice solution, I found a workaround by myself which enables uploading files of any size as expected. The way is changing Apache's root folder - to set as root the folder where the above HTML file (fupload.html) is, that's it!

Saying it a workaround instead of a solution because the issue remains to be strange and puzzling to me with regard to following two points:

(1) Inconsistency. Before my workaround, there seems to be a filesize threshold (30KB) existing: 
    below it upload works fine, or fails if above it! Why can such a threshold exist? and how does 
    the threshold happen to be a certain value of 30 KB? 
    -------------- 
    Note that all the file upload experiments were done under the settings allowing file sizes far 
    bigger than 30KB!

(2) Why could issue be gone simply by changing Apache's doc root folder?

=================================================================================

Further ref. information on experiment

Folder structure -

d:\phptst\ 
   xampp.html   (a href="./chap4/fupload.html"...)

d:\phptst\chap4\ 
   fupload.html,
   fupload.php

d:\phptst\chap4\up\file\ 
   (for uploaded files)

(1) Initially, Apache's root folder set to d:\phptst\, fupload.html is indirectly called and run 
    via xampp.html which contains a link to fupload.html, and here "30KB" threshold issue arises.

(2) Changed Apache's root to d:\phptst\chap4\, and call to run fupload.html directly, issue is gone!

=================================================================================

Based on above details and phenomenon, hope somebody can explain about essential reasons and what on earth the issue is.